# Android: Trouble Displaying a Random Number to Screen

Tags: android

I am trying to print a randomly generated integer to the screen. I looked at a couple other people's questions on how to do it and here is my attempt:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_program);
        TextView currentNumber = new TextView(this);
        // randNum() generates the random number and returns it (returns int)
        currentNumber.setText(randNum()); 
        this.setContentView(currentNumber);
    }
```

When I try to open the current activity, however, (emulator) the app stops working. What am I doing wrong? Also, I will be planning on allowing the user to generate a new random number later on and I want the display to update the `currentNumber` variable (overwriting the first number). Is this the best way of doing it or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`randNum()` I assume is an `int`. When you pass an `int` to `setText()`, it interprets as a resource, which you don't want.

Try this:

```
currentNumber.setText(String.valueOf(randNum()));
```

Or, if you prefer (less efficient, but maybe more readable):

```
currentNumber.setText(randNum() + "");
```

*NB: Also, when you get crashes in the future, please post the *full* red section of the LogCat for us to help you debug.*

Comment: Ok I will put the LogCat in next time.